# I have some difficulties commenting and understanding the calendar program

Tags: c

// This calendar example is provided by:
// http://www.codingunit.com Programming Tutorials

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int days_in_month[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
char *months[]=
{
" ",
"\n\n\nJanuary",
"\n\n\nFebruary",
"\n\n\nMarch",
"\n\n\nApril",
"\n\n\nMay",
"\n\n\nJune",
"\n\n\nJuly",
"\n\n\nAugust",
"\n\n\nSeptember",
"\n\n\nOctober",
"\n\n\nNovember",
"\n\n\nDecember"
};


int inputyear(void)
{
int year;

printf("Please enter a year (example: 1999) : ");
scanf("%d", &year);
return year;
}

int determinedaycode(int year)
{
int daycode;
int d1, d2, d3;

d1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;
d2 = (year - 1.)/ 100.;
d3 = (year - 1.)/ 400.;
daycode = (year + d1 - d2 + d3) %7;
return daycode;
}


int determineleapyear(int year)
{
if(year% 4 == FALSE && year%100 != FALSE || year%400 == FALSE)
{
    days_in_month[2] = 29;
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    days_in_month[2] = 28;
    return FALSE;
}
}

void calendar(int year, int daycode)
{
int month, day;
for ( month = 1; month <= 12; month++ )
{
    printf("%s", months[month]);
    printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n" );

    // Correct the position for the first date
    for ( day = 1; day <= 1 + daycode * 5; day++ )
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    // Print all the dates for one month
    for ( day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++ )
    {
        printf("%2d", day );

        // Is day before Sat? Else start next line Sun.
        if ( ( day + daycode ) % 7 > 0 )
            printf("   " );
        else
            printf("\n " );
    }
        // Set position for next month
        daycode = ( daycode + days_in_month[month] ) % 7;
}
}

int main(void)
{
int year, daycode, leapyear;

year = inputyear();
daycode = determinedaycode(year);
determineleapyear(year);
calendar(year, daycode);
printf("\n");
}
```

for example why there's a zero in days_in_month[]?

we learned about arrays, pointers and strings only, but the doctor asked us to do a complete project and to explain everything in it.I can understand most of it(I'm doing a lot of researches) but I need a clearer explanation of it. can you help me to comment this program please

Comment: Look at the `calendar` function, look at the loop iterating over months, what number does it start with? And remember that array indexes are zero-based.

Comment: "why there's a zero in days_in_month[]?" --> Notice array has 13 entries.

Comment: Who thought bringing floating-point math to dates was a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are zero based, that means the index of the first element is 0, not 1. The code you saw index the array with natural months, so the array has 13 elements, and the first element are only a placeholder, it is not used.

The result of this is, to get the number of first month, you can use do `days_in_month[month]`, no subtract by 1 needed, i.e. if it were 12 elements as you thought, you will need to do `days_in_month[month - 1]`. See below chart:

```
int days_in_month[]={0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
//         index:    0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
```

Comment: and why did they use #define true 1 & #define false 0?

Comment: @Beginner it's not necessary, C has bool type support, include stdbool.h and use true and false instead, remove that two lines :)

Comment: int inputyear()
    {
 int year;
 
 printf("Please enter a year (example: 1999) : ");
 scanf("%d", &year);
 return year;
    } what happens if I erase  return year;? what the difference with or without it?

Comment: @Beginner It's called return value, if you do not return anything in the function, the year will be lost when the function returns, other users could not have year.

Comment: And why did they put the year in a function itself? Why couldn't we put just in the int main()?

Comment: @Beginner You can put it in main function or create new functions,it's up to you

Comment: And please can you explain to me the daycode thing? Why we divided year-1 by 4 and then by 100 and then by 400?

Answer (score 1):

**For the why there is a zero in days_in_month?**

Arrays are zero indexed; first element is at index 0 while the last one in this array will be at (12 - 1).
So instead of using index 0 to refer to the month number 1, he just added a dummy element at the beginning.

Comment: so can I erase it and erase the "  " in char*month[]?

Comment: Yes, but the loops should start from 1 to N -1 instead

Comment: Can you please explain to me how they determined the code day? Why is it (year-1)? Before we divided by 4 and then 100 and then 400 to know if it's a leap year or not?